# Search hidden text with incremental search

Tags: visual-studio, ide, incremental-search

In Visual Stuido 2005 (C# .NET), is it possible to **search through hidden text** with the **incremental search** (Ctrl+I)? In the Find an Replace window I have the checkbox "Search hidden text" checked. But that doesn't seam to apply to the incremental search.

Comment: what do you mean by incremental search?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2005 you find this function in the menu Edit - Advanced - Incremental Search. In most keyboard mappings you can reach this through the short cut "Ctrl+I".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the behaviour in VS2010 - searching for hidden text uncollapses regions automatically, so you might consider an upgrade :).

In any case, why not use the shortcut Ctrl-M, Ctrl-L which "Toggles all previously marked hidden text sections between hidden and display states" before and after you use incremental search?

To be able to do this in one keystroke, create a macro (From Tools->Macros) with the following code:

Sub OutlineAndIncrementalSearch()

```
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleAllOutlining")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.IncrementalSearch")
End Sub
```

And bind this macro to Ctrl+I instead of the normal incremental search command.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though. The question was about how to do incremental search in *collapsed* (hidden) regions in *VS 2005* (I was thinking of 2008 when I put the bounty, but same difference). The whole *point* was to not have to toggle it, otherwise I might as well press Ctrl-F.

Comment: Not the solution I was looking for, but I have a feeling there just isn't a better one, so thanks. :)